# How bad is it to overstay my Schengen visa by 6 days?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I have a Schengen visa from Germany which says valid until 10/12/2014.

I landed in Germany today and to my surprise, the passport officer pointed out that my visa says stay allowed for 30 days only and I have already used 28 days in past visits. There is a section on my visa stamp which says "Duration of stay=30". But I wasn't aware or noticed this restriction before. My return flight is booked after 8 days so if I leave then, I will be overstaying by 6 days.

I was let in but advised to leave out of Schengen area by tomorrow.

Apart from the fact I will lose lot of money on my flight bookings, I came for a very urgent personal matter and I really need to stay for next 8 days here. I have read on forums that a few days overstay is fine.

Is it too risky to overstay by 6 days? I live and work in UK on a work visa. Will I have problem entering the UK? Do they verify if I have overstayed in a Schengen country?

Comment: Border guards have a bit of leeway but you can't assume that it's going to be fine. “Personal reasons” is actually a valid reason to get an extension, so you could in principle approach the authorities to try to get one but it's not guaranteed (and it's now Saturday so by Monday it might already be too late).

Comment: Also, living in the UK, you might have a lot of occasions to go to the Schengen area in the future, you want to be careful about that too.

Comment: why didn't you say something when the border official said you would have to leave the next day? You might have been able to arrange an extension then...

Comment: Thanks guys for the prompt reply.@ Relaxed ..Yes agreed..I am just brjng hopeful or want to be hopeful that it's a low risk given I'm going back within the allocated validity of the visa.

Comment: @Kate .thanks for your reply.Yes I tried .She was emphathetic of the situation but she said it's beyond her powers and to cobtact Munich consulate if I want but again that would be Monday and it will be anyways more than 30 days by then .A very tricky situation.Not sure what to do :(

Comment: well it might count for something that you tried.

Comment: @kate .  a good point indeed .But I can only try my luck on Monday with them!

Comment: @Dan Formally, the maximum stay is just as binding as the validity date. The fact that the visa is still valid is not enough to be safe, border guards are expressly supposed to check the duration of stay.

Comment: @Relaxed..thanks .I wasn't aware that they must calculate..in all 13+ occasions never a passport officer calculated days of stay ..May b I was lucky or may b they don't care much as you leaving .Guess it all boils down how lucky you are on the day .

Comment: what I'm wondering is in the event they don't calculate and let me leave without any issues ,will it still get captured anyways and impact any future applications..not sure if anyone will know the answer ? ..cheers

Comment: There's a passport control when you exit the Schengen area. They'll scan your passport and update the record for your visa in the database, and I'm pretty sure that a message will pop up on the official's screen telling them that you overstayed. The consequence may well be a fine *and* a Schengen visa interdiction lasting several years.

Comment: If you apply for an extension of any non-family UK visa and a sharp-eyed case worker spots a Schengen overstay, they will refuse on the grounds that you do not honour visa T's and C's. Even if your UK history is clean.

Comment: @Gilles Is that so? I was under the impression that there was no EU-wide record of all entries and exits and that border guards were supposed to rely on stamps for that.

Comment: @Dan If they don't notice and just give you an exit stamp, it would still be possible for someone else to notice the problem later on (e.g. when applying for another visa) based on the entry and exit stamps themselves.

Comment: Appreciate all the input guys ! Th x


@gayot...is your statement about impact to any internal UK visa extensions a case of cautious speculation or based on actual experience?..as I have never heard of any such cases or any such guidance/rules to evaluate an application on such grounds .please don't get me wrong .I'm just curious.

Because I'm not someone who has a disregard or dont want to follow the rules..it's just a messy situation and I'm sure this can happen to anyone 

Let me know your thoughts

Thanks
Dan

Comment: @Dan, actual experience, not speculation. http://www.ilpa.org.uk/ Also remember that if you go for permanent residence they require an EXACTLY tally of days in the UK and they get very detailed about it.   If you haven't been caught out before then...

Comment: I finally decided to bite the bullet and return back in UK now as today was last valid day  ..guess wasn't worth the risk